# Express.js routes do not work in docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, routes

When I run my Express.js application with `node app.js` everything works as expected, including this example route:

```
router.get('/config/get', function(req, res, next) {
    return res.json("hi");
});
```

However, when I build my docker image and run it, my browsers shows me my index page on this route. In fact, it shows my index page at pretty much every single route, nomatter if I set it up or not. So when I go to `/this/route/is/non-existing/` I see my index page as well. This only works through docker. When I visit this page by running the node application without docker, I get a 404.

Be aware that I use connect-history-api-fallback for my vue.js frontend. My app.js looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config()
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

var app = express();

// history mode for making vue.js router work: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html
app.use(history());

history({
    index: '/dist/index.html'
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/', indexRouter);

// serving vue.js prod build
app.use(express.static('dist'));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`${process.env.NAME} listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`))
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# use non-root user to run commands and give him chown permissions for the directory
USER node
COPY --chown=node:node ./backend .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Comment: where is your `/config/get` route , is it in index or user?

Comment: @MuhammadAli index